# Copy a range in an Excel sheet using vba

Tags: excel, vba

In below code I just want to copy a range from one sheet, which are some subsequent cells in the same row, to some subsequent cells in the same row in another sheet,

however the code does not work as expected? What do I do wrong? K and kk are just some integers, thanks for your help

```
Worksheets("spreadPar").Range(G & kk & ":" & Y & kk).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("EE static").Range(I & k & ":" & AA & k)
```

Comment: What are G, Y, I and AA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming kk and k contain the respective rows and G / Y, I / AA represent the columns, you probably mean (note the quotes):

```
Worksheets("spreadPar").Range("G" & kk & ":" & "Y" & kk).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("EE static").Range("I" & k & ":" & "AA" & k)
```